# Converting CAtlString (C++) to System::String (CLR) and vice versa

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Currently I have a DLL that uses **CAtlString** `(atlstr.h)` frequently as a parameter or as a return value for it's methods. As I am trying to create a wrapper for these methods (within **C++/CLI**) so that they can be used within C#, how would I convert from **CAtlString** to `System::String` and vice versa? Also if you recommend a much more adequate approach, feel free to comment.

Comment: It is a crappy string type since it is template specialization for TCHAR.  That stopped being useful a decade ago.  You can use the String(Char*) or String(SByte*) constructor to get a .NET string, Marshal.StringToXxx to get a CAtlString.  Pick the right one based on your compiler settings.

Comment: You convert the same way as you'd convert from `LPCTSTR` and to `LPCSTR`/`LPCTSTR`/`LPCWSTR` passing this further to `CAtlString` constructor, there are hundred topics on this.